# Makefile, Anonymous rm command executed at last

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Required stripe of the Makefile is as follows

```
PCS=$(wildcard $(PC)/*.pc)
SRCS=$(PCS:$(PC)/%.pc=$(SRC)/%.cpp)
OBJS=$(SRCS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)

f2db : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(INCS) $(LIBS) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS) f2db.cpp -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCS) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(SRC)/%.cpp : $(PC)/%.pc
    $(PROC) $< CODE=CPP CPP_SUFFIX=cpp INCLUDE=inc INCLUDE=/usr/include
    mv $(PC)/*.cpp $(SRC)
```

On gmake command invoke all is as expected except the remove command at last. The last two lines of the output as follows

```
gmake: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
rm src/fileName.cpp
```

Tool used GNU Make 3.80 in Solaris OS, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock skew warning is most likely because the directory you're building in is mounted from a remote system using something like NFS, etc., and the remote filesystem's clock is not synchronized with your local system clock.  Anyway, that's not related to the `rm` command.

The `rm` command is happening because the `src/fileName.cpp` is an [*intermediate file*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) and intermediate files are removed by make after they're built.

If you don't want them to be removed, just declare them as prerequisites of a rule so that they're not intermediate any longer:

```
f2db : $(OBJS) $(SRCS)
```